# How to resolve linker error "cannot find -lgcc_s"

Tags: c++, linux, linker, g++, static-libraries

I have 3 tiny files which I use to make a static library and an app:

***test.h***

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

class Test
{
    public:
        Test();
};

extern Test* gpTest;

#endif
```

***test.cpp***

```
#include "test.h"

Test::Test()
{
    gpTest = this;
}   

Test test;
```

***main.cpp***

```
#include "test.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Test* gpTest = NULL;

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

**BUILD**

```
g++ -c test.cpp -o test.o
ar cr test.a test.o
g++ -c main.cpp -o main.o
g++ main.o -o app -Wl,--whole-archive -L/home/dumindara/intest/test.a -Wl,-no--whole-archive
```

**ERROR (linking step)**

```
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.3/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I tried everything: using -static-libgcc and linking to static libstdc++. Can't get this to work. It is all due to --whole-archive flag. But I can't do without it.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten the actual error message? :)

Comment: :D. Yes, forgot error. Added.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think `--` is the problem here:

```
-Wl,-no--whole-archive
```

Try with

```
-Wl,-no-whole-archive
```

**edit**

About not seeing the test symbol in your app with nm app: I think you don't need `-L` since you give full path and name of test.a - do either

```
-Wl,--whole-archive -L/home/dumindara/intest/ -ltest -Wl,-no-whole-archive
```

or

```
-Wl,--whole-archive /home/dumindara/intest/test.a -Wl,-no-whole-archive
```

Comment: Yes, it links ok now. But I still can't see the `test` symbol in my app with `nm app`. What to do?

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, you saved my life!!! The lib was actually not getting liked I think. Now it works fine. :D

Answer (score 7):

You have a typo. -no--whole-archive should be --no-whole-archive. Fixing the typo fixes the linker error.

Answer (score 4):

With regards to the comments so far: just drop the -Wl option
entirely.  Let g++ do its thing.

As for not finding the symbol test with nm, why would you expect
anything else?  You don't use it, your program doesn't need it,
so it isn't pulled in.  (If for some reason you need to include
an object file which isn't referenced, e.g. because static
initializers will make it visible, then specify the object
file---don't put it in a library, which is the standard way of
saying don't include it unless needed.)

-- 
James Kanze

Comment: I will be actually using `gpTest`. Not in that form : it will be a vector holding all the version information about my static libraries linked to the program. So if linker throws away `test` it is a problem. I thought that is exactly what `--whole-archive` solves. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

whole-archive works, you are just not linking the lib. The correct thing to do is :

```
ar cr libtest.a test.o
```

and link with

```
-Wl,--whole-archive -L/home/dumindara/intest/ -ltest
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a note: whole-archive only works with static libraries (*.a) not with shared libraries (*.so) is my experience.

Comment: It'd be better to leave that as a comment rather than an answer. Please have a look at [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer).